# Can not build project because of using placeholders in application properties

Tags: java, spring, docker, kubernetes, config

Case: I want to build images which I can run in a `kubernetes cluster` later on. It seems to be very common to use placeholders in the `application.properties` file to set these values in the deployment description later on.

My `application.properties` looks like this:

```
...
spring.datasource.continueOnError=true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=embedded
catalogservice.baseurl=http://${CATALOG_SERVICE_ADDRESS}:${CATALOG_SERVICE_PORT}
spring.application.name=cartservice
...
```

I try to access these values using

```
@Value("${catalogservice.baseurl}")
String baseUrl;
```

When I try to build the project I recieve this exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'catalogRequestComponent': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'CATALOG_SERVICE_ADDRESS' in value "http://${CATALOG_SERVICE_ADDRESS}:${CATALOG_SERVICE_PORT}"
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:380) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context- ...

I googled lots but only found `ConfigMaps`, but these are to inject the values later on. Nevertheless the project will not build when I create a `kubernetes ConfigMap`, **or am I wrong**? 
I'd expect I need to create the images in the very first step, before creating the cluster and everything else.

**How do I pass my values**

Snippet of the `kubernetes deployment script:`

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myimage
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: CATALOG_SERVICE_ADDRESS <--
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: catalogmap
              key: catalog-address
       ...
```

These values are stored in a `ConfigMap`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: catalogmap
data:
  catalog-address: 192.168.178.10
```

Comment: where are you passing values for these placeholders `CATALOG_SERVICE_ADDRESS}`?

Comment: Why would that fail on building? That would only be the case if you have some tests that load the configuration. Judging from the little you posted here you are using Spring Boot and have Spring Boot tests. Thus you need to add a test configuration that contains values for those properties.

Answer (score 0):

All credits to @M. Deinum

Running `mvn install -DskipTests` solves all my problems.